# Keras ImageDataGenerator not working as expected

Tags: deep-learning, keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to build an autoencoder using Keras, based on `[this example][1]` from the docs. Because my data is large, I'd like to use a generator to avoid loading it into memory.

My model looks like:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', input_shape=(3, 256, 256)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same'))
model.add(Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same'))
model.add(Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same'))
model.add(Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(1, 3, 3, activation='sigmoid', border_mode='same'))

model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

My generator:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('IMAGE DIRECTORY', color_mode='rgb', class_mode='binary', batch_size=32, target_size=(256, 256))
```

And then fitting the model:

```
model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        samples_per_epoch=1,
        nb_epoch=1,
        verbose=1,
        )
```

I'm getting this error:

Exception: Error when checking model target: expected convolution2d_76 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 1)

That looks like the size of my batch rather than a sample. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is most likely due to the `class_mode='binary'`. It makes the generator produce binary classes, so the output has shape `(batch_size, 1)`, while your model produces a four dimensional output (since the last layer is a convolution).

I guess that you want your label to be the image itself. Based on the source of the `flow_from_directory` and the `DirectoryIterator` it uses, it is impossible to do by just changing the `class_mode`. A possible solution would be along the lines of:

```py
train_generator_ = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('IMAGE DIRECTORY', color_mode='rgb', class_mode=None, batch_size=32, target_size=(256, 256))
def train_generator():
    for x in train_iterator_:
        yield x, x
```

Note that I set `class_mode` to `None`. It makes the generator to return just the `image` instead of `tuple(image, label)`. I then define a new generator, that returns the image as both the input and the label.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! Now everything is working correctly. I was confused because I assumed it was talking about the input shape, but after implementing your solution I saw it was the output shape that was the problem.